# What type of electromagnetic radiation strikes the Earth's surface the most?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, waves, radiation

If you can could you lists the types of light from the greatest amount to the least amount (Ex: Visible, Infrared, Violet).

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://zebu.uoregon.edu/~imamura/122/lecture-3/stellar_spectra.html) is easier to read:

[image: solar spectrum]

There is more information in the link.

Answer (score 1):

this image shows what type of light enter's earth's atmosphere by what amount maybe it will help ypu[image]

visit the page below for detailed information

source   (http://www.windows2universe.org/earth/Atmosphere/earth_atmosph_radiation_budget.html)

Comment: Can you add a source for this picture?

Comment: here   http://www.windows2universe.org/earth/Atmosphere/earth_atmosph_radiation_budget.html